# Remove space to the vertical edges problem

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
%\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}% results the problem
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XXX@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Integrated QoS classes} & Applications example\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Interactive Voice} & VoIP Call\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Interactive Video} & Real-time Interactive & Online Gaming\\
                                   & Multimedia conferencing & Video Call\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Streaming Video} & Broadcast video & Enterprise TV\\
                                 & Multimedia streaming & IP/TV, Video\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Interactive (transactional) data} & Low latency data ERP application\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Bulk data ( background application )} & High throughput data FTP, e-mail, video contain distribution\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Best effort} & HTTP web browsing, Others\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Integrated QoS classes}%Different application type
\label{QoS classs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Removing vertical edge from right produce no problem. The output as follows -

[image]

But when I want to remove vertical edge from left the 1st column is not aligned.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
```

[image]

Comment: actually you have the same issue at the left and the right, you just don't see the space after Voip Call as that text is short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the first column spec be `@{}X` then you need to follow that in any multicolum specifications

```
\multicolumn{2}{l}
```

over-rides `@{}X` with `l`  which is not what you want, use

```
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}
```

similarly if you have any multicolumn spans ending in your final column they should have `l@{}` not `l`

Comment: Sorry for the edit... tried to undo but didn't found out how

Comment: @koleygr forgiven (but it did make the answer wrong:-)

Comment: @koleygr if you look at the list of previous versions in the "edited" link below the question then there is a `rollback` option to revert to any old version.

Comment: Yes... I show it... In first read I thought it was saying to replace in every multicolumn `l` with `l@{}`... But I read it again after edited to see how more beautifull it was with my picture under it :P... and the sentence freaked me out... lol (Thanks for the "rollback" -in both sences-... I will keep it in mind)

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem, I think adding @{} to first column of each row does the trick

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}% results the problem
%  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XXX@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Integrated QoS classes} & Applications example\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Interactive Voice} & VoIP Call\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\multirow{2}{*}{Interactive Video}} & Real-time Interactive & Online Gaming\\
                                   & Multimedia conferencing & Video Call\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\multirow{2}{*}{Streaming Video}} & Broadcast video & Enterprise TV\\
                                 & Multimedia streaming & IP/TV, Video\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Interactive (transactional) data} & Low latency data ERP application\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Bulk data ( background application )} & High throughput data FTP, e-mail, video contain distribution\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Best effort} & HTTP web browsing, Others\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Integrated QoS classes}%Different application type
\label{QoS classs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```